# Find and replace weird characters in the_content

Tags: the-content

So, I am using the following code to filter out certain letters.

```
$phrase = get_the_content();

$phrase = apply_filters('the_content', $phrase);
$replace = 'ï';

echo str_replace('Ã¯', $replace, $phrase);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to handle special characters that well. Any ideas?

Comment: The [multibyte string functions](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) maybe, but I don't see the "WordPress" in this question.

Comment: @s_ha_dum http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: Problems are not WordPress specific [simply because they appear in a WordPress context](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @s_ha_dum Look, if I post this in the regular stackexchange people whine that it's WordPress related. Stop being a Nazi.

Comment: 1) Godwin's Law. 2) Don't be rude. I haven't been. 3) The solution is pure PHP, as far as I can tell. Nothing personal. Chances are the [so] people haven't read our faq or perhaps don't know enough about WordPress to know what is or isn't due to WordPress code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?php
function replace_content($content)
{
  $search  = array('&', 'é', '—', '‘', '’', '“', '”');
  $replace = array('&', 'é', '—', '‘', '’', '“', '”');

  $content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
  return $content;
}

?>
```

Credit to [Harry on WordPress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-find-and-replace-wordpress-content-characters#post-2612822)